# How many python bitcoin wallets are there?

Tags: wallet, python, bitcoin-wallet-app

Is there a list of legit Python Bitcoin wallets or even other cryptocurrencies?

I did a Google search and got no clear results.

Comment: Hi AirGap, I've been seeing a few of your questions not really fit well in the scope of topics we collect here. Please check out our [tour] to get an overview what sort of content we collect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrum is one of the oldest Bitcoin wallet that is still maintained and it is written in python: https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum

Armory is another one but it is no longer maintained:
https://github.com/goatpig/BitcoinArmory